# Filter JQuery list by name, price... json array, JQuery.grep()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I just got amazing feedback for my previous question but now I'm stuck again.

I have a JQuery listview displaying my json array. It's working fine.
But now, I'd like to be able to filter my results by name or price. I looked up the jQuery.grep() method but can't really get it to work correctly.

If anyone could give some pointers on how I could get this to work, it would be greatly appreciated once again.

Heres the code I have so far :

js file :

```
    // Json array
    var productList = {"products": [
        {"description": "Product 1", "price": "9.99$"},
        {"description": "Product 2", "price": "9.97$"},
        {"description": "Product 3", "price": "8.52$"},
        {"description": "Product 4", "price": "5.24$"},
        {"description": "Product 5", "price": "4.21$"}
    ]
    };
```

```
function loadList() {

//  var list = document.getElementById('productList');
    var list = $("#productList").listview();
    list.sort();

   $(productList.products).each(function(index){
    $(list).append('<li id="listitem">' + this.description + "  " +
            "    :     " +  this.price + '</li>');

   });

   $(list).listview("refresh");

}<code>
```

HTML file :

`<html>
<head>
    <title>Product List</title>
    &meta;
    <script src="@=site.cfg.resources.url@/test.js"></script>


</head>

<body onLoad="loadList()">


<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" id="header">
        <h1>Product List</h1>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <ul id="productList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
        </ul>
    </div>



</div>



</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) should do what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Depends what exactly you want to filter by. Just have the function that you pass in return true for the elements you want to keep, and false otherwise.

Also, I'd call filter on $(productList.products), if I'm understanding what you're doing correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not sure I quite get it. I'm pretty new to web development and still unsure about a lot of things.

I'll try and figure this out, I'll check out the .filter method.

Thanks !

Comment: $(productList.products).filter(function () { return parseFloat(this.price) < 9;}), for instance, would essentially return the subset of products cheaper than $9, for instance. (Instead of using regex to figure out what the price is, it's easier in this case to just use parseFloat)

Comment: Worked !

Thanks for the help, appreciate it. I'll look more into it to be able to sort it by name and other filters. 

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

[$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

is worth checking out.